# Graphics horribly corrupted on Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox, showing random strips of pixelated colors

Tags: server, apt, virtualbox, desktop-environments

Inside a VirtualBox VM, I have installed myself an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Server installation. However, when I installed the `ubuntu-desktop` package and rebooted, this happened:

[image]

Exact command I used: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
..and then a `reboot` command.

This just seems like a corrupted top-left portion of the screen, as my cursor can appear in view (but corrupted):

[image]

This is a purely graphical issue because I can use the keyboard to successfully progress to a desktop:

[image]

Note: On startup it shows correct graphics for a split-second then reverts to glitch.

[image]

Any help on this?

Comment: Note that the screen is perfectly fine for a split second after the machine starts everything. Then the resolution messes up and the graphics die.

Comment: The pattern of visual defects in your screenshots is similar defects that are caused by a bad stick of RAM memory in a physical machine.  As a troubleshooting device please try to add more RAM to the virtual machine and check if the problem goes away.

Comment: I gave it 128 MB of graphics memory and 12 GB of RAM - for a split second it did show the login screen like before (snagged a screenshot [here](https://puu.sh/tc0iW/e92ecadc77.png)) but after that, [this happened again](https://puu.sh/tc0kT/caaad24bc0.png)

Comment: Possibly. Maybe this is why Google Chrome has been killing random tabs. Let me try giving it less RAM then.

Comment: Same result. Proper screen for a split-second and then [this](https://puu.sh/tc0uc/1821076247.png).

Comment: Let's [move to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51237/discussion-between-dev-and-karel)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have also experienced this problem before and it is easy to work around:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to text terminal and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back to GUI (alternatively <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> in the case of some newer Ubuntu versions – simply try it if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> does not work).

If your host is Linux, too, the mentioned keystrokes will influence the host machine. Use the [Host key](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#globalsettings) instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> to influence the guest.

References:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/1443853
- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13615
- [How do I switch between console mode and GUI in 17.10 and newer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027/how-do-i-switch-between-console-mode-and-gui-in-17-10-and-newer)

Comment: I had the same problem with Linux Mint and this works for that too.

Comment: With an Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10 Guest, you need to use <CTRL>-<HOST-KEY>-<F2> followed by <CTRL>-<HOST-KEY>-<F1>.

Answer (score 4):

This may be obvious to some, but in my instance (Ubuntu Host), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> switched the entire host video mode, and switching back didn't change the status of the guest video.  The trick was to use <kbd>HOST</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (e.g. the RIGHT <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, no <kbd>ALT</kbd>), and then <kbd>HOST</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back.

Answer (score 2):

Hit this scrambled/distorted screen today with 18.04 installer. I fixed it by increasing the video memory of the VM.