# will a ubuntu reinstall just overwrite

Tags: 16.04, reinstall

My Ubuntu partition lost the login screen.  The graphics are off and is unreadable.  Will a reinstall just overwrite the OS or clobber my data too?  I the LiveCD.  Ubuntu  16.0.4

Comment: By default, it will delete everything. You have to select the "something else" option and make sure the Ubuntu partitions are not to be formatted.

Comment: I do reinstalls sometimes and only "something else" allows you to choose not to format a partition. I do this to keep my HOME folder

Comment: I do as u say, get a partition table.  highlight the Ubuntu partition.  Click on "Install Now".  Get a message: "No root file system defined.  Please correct this from the partitioning menu."  If I double click on the Ubuntu partition in the partition table, I get a popup that gives a (partition) size, a field "Use As",  a checkbox for format, and a mount point.  i assume the mount point is "/" &  the "Use As" is the same.  in the partition table it is "ext4 journal file".  i get a warning about files being erased &  another partition "sda6" being used as a swap file.  "sda6" already exist.

Comment: well, it did work.  i got a message that some things couldn' t be reinstalled after installation.  haven't figured out what that is yet.  but, all my data seems intact.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the graphics are unreadable, try Control+Alt+F1 and then Control+Alt+F7. That would switch to the text terminal and then back. That fixed my issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868347/graphics-horribly-corrupted-on-ubuntu-how-to-fix).

Comment: i tried that.  i do get a command line.  but, it doesn't switch back.  i get a blank screen.