# Virtualbox Ubuntu 16.04 Guest - 3D Acceleration Pixel Flickering

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 guest on a Windows 10 host with VirtualBox 5.2.4. I have an Nvidia GTX 1050 graphic card.

I've followed all the necessary steps to enable 3D acceleration as in [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/3d-acceleration-for-ubuntu-guests-v2), and everything seems to have worked correctly, if it wasn't for a constant pixel flickering affecting transparencies. The flickering also affects the upper bar randomly. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Ubuntu graphic glitch]

The system seems to run a bit faster, and it's SORT of usable, but the glitch is very annoying. The solution given for [this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868347/graphics-horribly-corrupted-on-ubuntu-16-04-in-virtualbox-showing-random-strips) problem didn't help.

What else can I try?

Comment: having the same problem, 5.2.8 is supposed to fix this but didn't work for me

Comment: After months I found out that the solution for me was to make Virtual Box use the NVidia graphic card instead of the integrated intel one!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue as you after enabling 3D acceleration but the solution (at least for me) is [in this article](https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/guide-speed-up-ubuntu-virtualbox/), at the very end.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager && ccsm
> ```
>
> Go to **OpenGL** and untick **Framebuffer Object**. Also, you might want to disable effects, such as fading windows, animations and window decoration.

Hope that this will do the trick for you too.

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it, thank you

Comment: This 'almost' worked, it removed many glitches, but there still some artifacts from time to time, thanks anyway!

Comment: This solved the problem for some version. But unfortunately the problem reappeared after upgrade to virtualbox 5.2.12 :(